# Simple React Routes not showing up

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am following a very simple tutorial on react routes, and for some reason, this code block does not render the component on the screen. Here is my code in *App.js*:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import SigninPage from "./pages/signin";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={SigninPage} exact />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I replace `<Route path="/" component={SigninPage} exact />` with `<SigninPage />`, then the component shows up.

I have no warnings or errors, and my `react-router-dom` version is `6.0.0-beta.0`. I have tried running `npm start` again and restarting my computer. I very much appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

I figured it would be useful to include *signin.js*:

```
import React from "react";

const SigninPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Signin</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SigninPage;
```

Comment: I'm unable to create whatever error you're hitting in codesandbox. It looks fine to me. https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-waterfall-mqu41?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Are there any errors in the js console?

Comment: They are using version 6.0.0-beta.0, which has a slightly different API

Comment: @Nick thank you for your comment; I had the wrong version of `react-router-dom` installed. For some reason, that was the default when everything got set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-router-dom` version seems incorrect here, the API has changed slightly in V6, so if you try the stable version, everything will work just fine.

You can change the version to either `@latest` which points to a stable version or install a specific version.

`npm i packageName@versionNumber`

```js
npm uninstall react-router-dom
npm install react-router-dom@latest or npm install react-router-dom@5.2
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the comment! I ran both `npm install react-router-dom@5.2` and `npm install react-router@5.2` and my code worked. Thanks again! I would upvote, but StackOverflow has not given me this privilege yet...